# Does amending taxes affect future QBI loss carryforward?

Tags: united-states, s-corporation, amended-tax-return

When an S-Corp shareholder deducts losses, those losses reduce subsequent years' QBI Deduction (Form 8995, line 3 `Qualified business net (loss) carryforward from the prior year`). But what happens if a shareholder amends taxes from several years ago in a way which reduces the QBI loss? Does that shareholder then amend all the following years?

#### An example:

An S-Corp shareholder had a loss of $30K in 2020. They deducted this from their taxes, and the loss carried forward into 2021 and 2022 (reducing / eliminating their QBI Deduction).

Later, the S-Corp gets an ERTC, and the shareholder's 2020 $30K loss is reduced to $25K. I know they must amend their 2020 returns and pay the extra tax. What I am wondering is if they would then amend their 2021 and 2022 returns to get a larger QBI Deduction, and lower their tax burden for those years. (Is it allowable? beneficial? required?)

Answer (score 1):

> What I am wondering is if they would then amend their 2021 and 2022 returns to get a larger QBI Deduction, and lower their tax burden for those years.
>
> (Is it allowable?

Yes

> beneficial?

Do the math.

> required?)

No.